# One Click UN-subscribe email service through java

Tags: java, security, email

I am working on the un-subscribing email service through un-subscribe link for an web application.

Email with un-subscribe link will be generated from a java class using `MD5` algorithm. currently, i am appending the email id's in the form of encrypted hash with the link as,

```
<a href="http://server name/mailid=3f37c9628c8953d3fdfb0f8" >
```

'3f37c9628c8953d3fdfb0f8' string contains email'id of the user . i am updating the service subscription after validating it.

Does this process is secure ? or should i go for any other algorithms to make it more secure ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you want to make it secure, salt the hash. But seriously, do you believe anyone is going to be making an effort to falsify unsubscribes?

Comment: @keshlam That depends on the context.

Comment: @keshlam i can you , but to satisfy my manager need to make it more secure. what do you mean by `salt the hash` ?

Comment: What does `'3f37c9628c8953d3fdfb0f8' string contains email'id of the user` mean exactly? San Krish, would you mind elaborating?

Comment: @Thihara it is the `md5` hash value of the email id .

Comment: In these cases we use SHA1, which is more secure than MD5. See these link for instance: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19705/is-sha1-better-than-md5-only-because-it-generates-a-hash-of-160-bits

Comment: If you want it to be secure, you don't want to simply use MD5 of the userID, because that's too easy to recognize and thus fake. You want to use an encryption which will prevent that. This is generally done by "salting" the computation, to produce a hash that can't easily be replicated. This can be as simple as appending some nontrivial string to the userID before computing the hash. You will get more and better advice if you take this to the [Cryptography](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/) or [Information Security](http://security.stackexchange.com/) discussions.

Comment: @keshlam thanks for your advice , will try salting the userid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the unsubscribe link contain a randomly generated hash that's mapped to the user id internally in your data store.

You can also make the hash invalid after some specified time.

But keshlam has a point. Before you go to all that trouble make sure it's worth it with you context.

Comment: Do you want me to generate the random hash 'user id'.  i have done the same already.

Comment: No don't hash the user ID. Hash some randomly generated value, and keep them mapped in you application side (in a DB etc.).

Comment: what do you think on using `HMAC` . does that sound better when compared to this

Comment: Yes HMAC seem better.